# How to read embedded objects from a doc file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read embedded documents in a .doc file using POIFS file system. According to this there is an ObjectPool directory which contains all embedded documents especially for a doc file.
I found the directory but don't know the way to read these documents. 
Please suggest any way to read these documents. If POIFS is not the suitable way then please suggest any other library.

My code is:

```
 public static void ReadCSV(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    for (HSSFObjectData obj : workbook.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {
        //the OLE2 Class Name of the object
        System.out.println("Objects : "+ obj.getOLE2ClassName()+ "   2 .");
        String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName(); 
        if (oleName.equals("Worksheet")) {
            // some code to process embedded excel file;
        } else if (oleName.equals("Document")) {
            System.out.println("Document");
            DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode) obj.getDirectory();
            HWPFDocument embeddedWordDocument = new HWPFDocument(dn,fs);
            System.out.println("Doc : " + embeddedWordDocument.getRange().text());
            // want to extract document not text into a doc file
            //************************
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\log.txt");
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
            //************************
         }  else if (oleName.equals("Presentation")) {
            // some code to process embedded power point file;
         } else {
            // some code to process other kind of embedded files;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI documentation on embedded files](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/embeded.html) and on [reading entries from within a file](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/how-to.html#reading_poifsfilesystem)?

Comment: Yes I have read these links and tried in the same way. I found the location of the embedded files but unable to read the contents of the files. Please provide a sample code to read the contents from embedded files.

Comment: Anybody please suggest any generic way to extract and read embedded files.

Comment: Did you try using the code on the Apache POI website? If so, what problem did you find? If not, why not? If you show your code, we can help you a lot better...

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have found the way to read the contents of the embedded document but I want to extract the whole embedded file. I have inserted the code in the question. Please see the code and help me.

Comment: Your question talks about reading embedded documents, which your code looks to do. However, your code has a comment about saving the file, which is different. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have read the contents of embedded files but I also want to write (extract) embedded file as it is on the disk because there may be a case that the embedded file may contain other embedded files.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I have solved the problem with your guidance.